# How to add a query string in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, string

I want to add a query string to URL in my website using JavaScript. How can I do that?

I tried many things but none worked.

I need to add a query string to my website, because I'm going to create some functions which are going to need query strings to work properly.

Comment: You just add the query string to your links, like `<a href="http://www.yoursite.com/page.aspx?querystringparameter1=575&anotherparameter=3`

Comment: So, if you're doing it using javascript, keep in mind that it'll act like a page-refresh, using `window.location.href = window.location.href + '?querystringparameter1=575&anotherparamet‌​er=3;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var currentURL = window.location.href;
window.location.href = currentURL + yourQueryString;
```

If you're working with a single page website, you can use window.location.hash instead.